# Meu navegador não está conseguindo seguir a rota corretamente e está retornando "erro 404"

Tags: react, typescript

Aqui está meu código:

-Rotas

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router, 
  Routes,
  Route, 
} from "react-router-dom"

import { Home } from '../pages/Home';
import { Cart } from '../pages/Cart';
import { Catalog } from '../pages/catalog';

export function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/Cart' element={<Cart />} />
        <Route path='/catalog' element={<Catalog />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  )
}



-App.tsx

import { useState } from "react"
import { Tweet } from "./components/Tweet"
import {AppRoutes} from './routes/Routes'

function App() {

  return (
    <AppRoutes />
  )
}

export default App


-tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src", "routes", "routes/Routes.tsx"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Comment: Olá amigo. Lembre-se de usar as ferramentas de formatação disponíveis para postar código... Quanto ao problema, é um pouco difícil de alguém ajudar sem poder reproduzir localmente... 404 significa não existente - tu tens certeza que os endereços estão corretos?

Comment: Então, sim. O código estava funcionando normalmente até o momento em que mudei a pasta "routes" de lugar. Depois que parou de funcionar até tentei colocar de volta mas não voltou a rodar. Acredito que o problema está nas rotas pois em nenhum lugar indica erro, nem no Vs Code ou no navegador

Comment: Amigo, ao que parece pelo que tu descreveste, o problema está nas tuas rotas. É impossível que alguém consiga te ajudar (além de te dizer - verifica se as rotas estão corretas) sem reproduzir exatamente o teu ambiente (inclusive com a localização de cada dependência). A minha recomendação é que tu vá debugando e ajustando as rotas até encontrares o erro... boa sorte...

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado!
(como marco a pergunta como respondida?)

Comment: Só é possível marcar como respondida quando há uma resposta nela. Se há uma resposta e ela soluciona o caso, quem pergunta pode selecionar como resposta correta (aparece um V verde para ser marcado)

Comment: Podes responder algo aqui então pra mim marcar como respondido e encerrar a pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta, mais ou menos o que coloquei nos comentários...

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro que estás tendo significa [página inexistente](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/website-creation/what-does-the-404-not-found-error-mean/). Provavelmente está acontecendo porque os recursos - que, de acordo com os comentários que tu colocaste, existiam - foram deletados ou movidos para um lugar que não bate com as rotas que definiste.

Para resolver isso, tu precisas ir ajustando as rotas e debugando até encontrares o erro. Vá ajustando os caminhos (path) de cada rota e veja se eles passam a ser encontrados. Não há muito que a gente possa ajudar além disso, pois precisaríamos reproduzir com exatidão o ambiente onde teu software está rodando para reproduzir e corrigir.